# Oracle: Changing VARCHAR2 column to CLOB

Tags: oracle, database

I have an encountered an issue where the data I was trying to store in my varchar2(4000) column was too big, so I wish to change the column to one more suitable for storing large amounts of textual data. Specifically, a serialized array.

1. Firstly, is CLOB the best data type for me to use for this purpose? Is there a more appropriate data type?
2. Secondly, when I try to alter the column using the usual snyntax:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column CLOB
   ```

   I get the following error: **ORA-22858: invalid alteration of datatype**

   What's the most straightforward way to alter this table without losing any data?

Comment: Make sure to commit BEFORE droping the column.
Or copy operation will not be commited and you will loose all your data.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The most straightforward way, given that the operation of moving from a `varchar` column to a `CLOB` is disallowed, would be to create a new column and move the data from the old column to the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ADD (foo CLOB);
UPDATE some_table SET foo = old_column;
ALTER TABLE some_table DROP COLUMN old_column;
ALTER TABLE some_table RENAME COLUMN foo TO old_column;
```

Comment: Yep. The OP's syntax was right but the operation is just not allowed.

Answer (score 11):

The VARCHAR2 column cannot be directly converted to CLOB but it can be done in 2 steps:

- Convert column datatype from VARCHAR2 to LONG.
- Convert column datatype from LONG to CLOB.

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column long;
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column clob;
```

Comment: ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype

Answer (score 3):

For Oracle 11g:

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column long;
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column clob;
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what OP was trying?