# Error when trying to use custom datatype in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, plsql, types

I am trying to create a table where two columns have custom data types that I created. When I select the datatype from my schema and try to save the table, I get the following error. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Does the field already contain data?  Most likely it is not able to convert some existing value to the new data type.  Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402510/oracle-changing-varchar2-column-to-clob.

Comment: It might help if you posted what you really did (those "create table ... select datatype ... save table ..." things, not just the error you got).